# ROS2 Turtlebot3 fails with numpy not found

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Environment**

- Turtlebot3 Waffle
- Intel NUC i5
- Ubuntu 18.04
- ROS2 Crystal

**Goal**

I am replacing the Joule on my Turtlebot3 Waffle with a NUC. I want more capability on the Waffle making it on par with typical Turtlebot2 systems. Furthermore, the Joule is no longer supported. I know that the NUC is not an officially supported either. I am posting this question as a benefit to others that may be interested in Intel Core enabled solutions.

**Details**

ROS2 installed fine. The examples in the "Using colcon to build package" tutorial built and the publish/subscribe example ran well.

I ran into trouble with the ROS2 Turtlebot3 install [Robotis eManual Section 15](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2/). In particular see Section 15.1.1.3 "Install Turtlebot3 ROS2 Packages".

`colcon build --symlink-install` fails. I get the following error during the cv_bridge build. See a detailed log at this message end.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

apt tells me python-numpy is not installed. So I install it.

```
$ apt list --installed python-numpy 
     Listing... Done
$ sudo apt install python-numpy
$ apt list --installed python-numpy
    Listing... Done
    python-numpy/bionic,now 1:1.13.3-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

Furthermore, a python example program using numpy now executes properly. It didn't run before.

I still get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'` error.

**Question**

How do I fix this?

**Complete colcon build log**

```
$ colcon build --symlink-install
Starting >>> nav2_common
Starting >>> nav_2d_msgs
Starting >>> angles
Starting >>> behaviortree_cpp
Finished <<< nav2_common [1.54s]                                   
Starting >>> nav2_msgs
Finished <<< angles [3.70s]                                      
Starting >>> nav2_voxel_grid
[Processing: behaviortree_cpp, nav2_msgs, nav2_voxel_grid, nav_2d_msgs]
Finished <<< nav2_voxel_grid [43.7s]                                   
Starting >>> cv_bridge
--- stderr: cv_bridge                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:27 (message):
  Could not determine the NumPy include directory, verify that NumPy was
  installed correctly.


---
Failed   <<< cv_bridge  [ Exited with code 1 ]
Aborted  <<< nav_2d_msgs                               
Aborted  <<< behaviortree_cpp                          
Aborted  <<< nav2_msgs                                                     

Summary: 3 packages finished [4min 35s]
  1 package failed: cv_bridge
  3 packages aborted: behaviortree_cpp nav2_msgs nav_2d_msgs
  1 package had stderr output: cv_bridge
  48 packages not processed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328472/ros2-turtlebot3-fails-with-numpy-not-found/) by [Ed C.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23761/ed-c./) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2019-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-07-13**:
Perhaps you need the python3 version of numpy?

**Comment by [Ed C.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23761/ed-c./) on 2019-07-13**:
Thanks. That was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install the Python3 version of numpy

```
sudo apt install python3-numpy
```

---

Originally posted by [Ed C.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23761/ed-c./) with karma: 38 on 2019-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0